# Android OpenGl 2.0 Texturing with shaders

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures

So, I received this code from another post to SO. It seems to be the most complete working  code for adding textures in openGl 2.0 with shaders in android. How does he know what integer to pass into textureResourceId, and how do I set-up a resource Id to the .png files I put into my project?

Here's the link to the SO post I'm reffering to:

[Android OpenGL|ES 2.0 Texturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750542/android-opengles-2-0-texturing)

And here's the Square Code:

```
 public class Square{

private static final String TAG = "Square";

public float[] rotation = {0.0f,0.0f,45.0f};
public float[] scale = {100.0f,100f,100f};
public float[] position = {0.0f,0.0f,100f};
public float[] color = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

private int textureRef = -1;

private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

protected int DRAW_MODE = GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES;
protected int mProgram; 
protected int mPositionHandle;
protected Vertex vertices;
protected Vertex texture;

private int mColorHandle;

private int vsTextureCoord;
private int fsTexture;  

protected float[] result_matrix = new float[16];    

private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "attribute vec3 vPosition;" +
                "attribute vec2 TexCoordIn;" +
                "varying vec2 TexCoordOut;" +
                "void main() {" +
                //the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vec4(vPosition,1.0);" +
                "  TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;" +
                "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "uniform sampler2D Texture;" +
                "varying lowp vec2 TexCoordOut;" +                             
                "void main() {" +                   
                "  gl_FragColor = vColor*TexCoordOut*Texture;" +
                "}";    
//I am fully aware that I am not using the texture by assigning the colour, but until I can actually SEND the texture through, there would be no point.
static float squareCoords[] = { -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
                                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
                                 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
                                 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right


private short drawOrder[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 }; // order to draw vertices

public Square(int textureResourceId) {

    int vertexShader = GFXUtils.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = GFXUtils.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables
    textureRef = GFXUtils.textures.get(textureResourceId);

    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
    vertices = new Vertex(squareCoords, drawOrder, GFXUtils.COORDS_PER_VERTEX);

    texture = new Vertex (new float[]
            {               
                1.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f,
            }, GFXUtils.COORDS_PER_TEXTURE);   

    DRAW_MODE = GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN;
}

private void getHandles()
{

    //get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
    if (mPositionHandle == -1) Log.e(TAG, "vPosition not found");
    //get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
    if (mColorHandle == -1) Log.e(TAG, "vColor not found");

    //get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    if (mMVPMatrixHandle == -1) Log.e(TAG, "uMVPMatrix not found");

    //get handle to texture coordinate variable
    vsTextureCoord = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "TexCoordIn");
    if (vsTextureCoord == -1) Log.e(TAG, "TexCoordIn not found");

    //get handle to shape's texture reference
    fsTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "Texture");
    if (fsTexture == -1) Log.e(TAG, "Texture not found");

}

private void translateRotateScale(float[] matrix, float[] perspectiveMatrix)
{       
    for (int i= 0; i < perspectiveMatrix.length;i++)
        matrix[i] = perspectiveMatrix[i];

    Matrix.translateM(matrix, 0, position[0], position[1], position[2]);
    Matrix.rotateM(matrix, 0, rotation[0], 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.rotateM(matrix, 0, rotation[1], 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Matrix.rotateM(matrix, 0, rotation[2], 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    Matrix.scaleM(matrix, 0, scale[0], scale[1], scale[2]);            
}

public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    rotation[2]+=0.5;
    // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
    GFXUtils.checkGlError("using program");

    //Housekeeping
    getHandles();
    translateRotateScale(result_matrix, mvpMatrix);
    //end housekeeping

    // Set color for drawing the shape
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);     

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, result_matrix, 0);
    GFXUtils.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    // Prepare the shape coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, GFXUtils.COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            GFXUtils.vertexStride, vertices.floatBuffer);
    GFXUtils.checkGlError("load vertex buffer");

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vsTextureCoord, GFXUtils.COORDS_PER_TEXTURE,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 
            GFXUtils.textureStride, texture.floatBuffer);
    GFXUtils.checkGlError("load texture buffer - " + vsTextureCoord);

    // Enable a handle to the shape vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GFXUtils.checkGlError("enable position handle");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vsTextureCoord);
    GFXUtils.checkGlError("enable texture handle");

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GFXUtils.checkGlError("activtexture");
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureRef);
    GFXUtils.checkGlError("bindtexture");
    GLES20.glUniform1i(fsTexture, 0);
    GFXUtils.checkGlError("uniformi");
    //Draw the shape
    GLES20.glDrawElements(DRAW_MODE, vertices.numIndeces, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, vertices.indexBuffer);
    GFXUtils.checkGlError("glDrawArrays with " + vertices.numVertices + " vertices");

    //Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vsTextureCoord);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GFXUtils.checkGlError("glDisableVertexAttribArray for position");

}
```

}

My Main Activity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

GLSurfaceView myGL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myGL=new MySurface(this);   
    setContentView(myGL);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

//---------------------------------Open GL-------------------------------------------------------
class MySurface extends GLSurfaceView
{
    private MyRenderer myRend;

    public MySurface(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        myRend=new MyRenderer();
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        setRenderer(myRend);
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }
}


Square mSquare;
float [] mViewMatrix=new float[16];
float [] mMVPMatrix=new float[16];
float [] mProjectionMatrix=new float[16];
private float[] mRotationMatrix=new float[16];

class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
            GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1f);

            mSquare=new Square(R.drawable.brick_texture);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

        mSquare.draw(mMVPMatrix);


    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        float ratio = (float) width / height;
        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 2, 50);

    }   

}
```

}

Comment: Where does GFXUtils come from? Without documentation, I can't be completely sure. But based on the descriptive name and how it's used, there's a very high probability that it's the resource id of the texture image you want to load.

Comment: That's what I thought. So, he initiates it as an integer, and I thought the id would be a string similar to: res/drawable/image_id. So how do I create the integer value of the resource id for the texture image?

Comment: If your resource is named `myimage`, you can get the integer resource id as `R.drawable.myimage`.

Comment: I am right when I use: gl_FragColor = vColor*TexCoordOut*Texture;?

Comment: No, that shader code doesn't look right. To sample the texture, you have to use a `texture2D()` call, and then use the result of that as part of calculating the fragment color.

Comment: So, I looked over the guy's code, and I noticed that loadTexture() in the GFX class is never used. I think I'm missing a portion of the code in the mainActivity class, considering he didn't post that part, because the textureImage2D() method is used in the loadTexture() method. Do you think you could post what the main activity class would look like?

Comment: I'll update my question and post what my Main looks like.